# How to compare 2 time values in php

Tags: php

I want to check current times is greater than `12.00 pm` or not in PHP 
I have tried this code

```
<?php
       date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
       $currentTime = date( 'h:i:s A', time () );
       echo $currentTime;
              //var_dump($currentTime);


       $tm="12:00:00 PM";
      $from= date("h:i:s A", strtotime($tm));
      echo $from;
      //var_dump($from);
      if($currentTime>$from){
      echo "success";
       }
 ?>
```

but it is comparing times as string. If the current time is `2.00pm` it is not printing success.

Comment: They are strings, so they are compared as strings. Compare them asks times (or timestamps, integers). Basically get rid of the calls to `date`, which is for formatting dates and times as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the binary timestamps for calculations and comparing, and convert them only to text for displaying. This is more efficient than managing all as time strings. Add differences can be build by a simple and fast subtraction (`$delta = $currentTime - $from`).

The modified code may look like this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$currentTime = time(); // very fast function
echo date('h:i:s A',$currentTime);

$tm="12:00:00 PM";
$from = strtotime($tm);
echo date('h:i:s A',$from);

if ( $currentTime > $from ){
   $delta = currentTime - $from;
   echo "success, delta $delta seconds";
}
?>
```